# Wordpress: Retrieve a value from database

Tags: php, sql, database, wordpress

I'm trying to retrieve a text value for my field from database using this query:

```
<input type="text" name="last_link" id="last_link" value="<?php global $wpdb; $user_ID = get_current_user_id(); $result= $wpdb->get_results( 'SELECT last_link FROM users WHERE ID = $user_ID'); echo $result; ?>"
```

What I receive is : 
[image]

I've searched a lot but all I could find is [Class Reference/wpdb](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb)

and I was't able to find my mistake.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

USE `$wpdb->get_var('your query')` instead `$wpdb->get_results()`

I have found Error in query which is you forget the table prefix that is required to retrieve info from wordpress pre defined tables.

Use `global $table_prefix` along with `$wpdb`
**Like this : `global $wpdb,$table_prefix`**

Also make sure your column `last_link` is added to `tableprefix_users`'s table 
For your requirement use below code to retrieve info.

```
<?php

global $wpdb,$table_prefix;
$user_ID = get_current_user_id();
$last_link = $wpdb->get_var('SELECT last_link FROM '.$table_prefix.'users WHERE ID = '.$user_ID);
?>

<input type="text" name="last_link" id="last_link" value="<?php echo $last_link;?>">
```

As stated in Documentation

> Generic, multiple row results can be pulled from the database with
>   **get_results**. The function returns the entire query result **as an array**.
>   Each element of this array corresponds to one row of the query result
>   and, like get_row, can be an object, an associative array, or a
>   numbered array. If no matching rows are found, or if there is a
>   database error, the return value will be **an empty array**. If your
>   **$query** string is empty, or you pass an invalid **$output_type**, NULL will
>   be returned.

Comment: get_var() returns nothing. Maybe the problem is in my query?

Comment: your welcome :) I believe you didn't get the answer only along with the info ;)